# Semantic UI sidebar to close if you click outside

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I want to close the sidebar if the user click outside

```
$( "#menu" ).click(function() {
$('.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
});
```

http://semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('body').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).prop('id') == 'menu' || $(e.target).hasClass('sidebar')) return false;
    $('.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this code hide the whole side bar and the sidebar cant comeback

Comment: its working but at the same time it conflict my button event, when I click inside the of sidebar its also close

Comment: @superdb try again, one last time.

Comment: its still not working take note I'm using cakephp for backend